# Linux terminal command

Tags: linux

I'm trying to install Oracle SQL developer but it says the package is not signed, how can i solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Your image does not agree with your description.  Your image shows you are missing other packages that need to be installed before or alongside this one.

Comment: Bad Linux hygiene, don't download files to `/usr`...

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzRHo.jpg)

I'm trying to install Oracle SQL developer but it says the package is not signed, how can i solve this problem?